# MySQL Query Returning Different GROUP BY Sum When Unrelated Item Is Added/Removed

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a sports website. It generates a dynamic query that tallies points based on whether a results row is present with a timestamp between two dates.

This is the actual query so please excuse its lengthiness.

```
SELECT   sum(totalpoints), 
         playerid 
FROM     fch_consolidated_results 
WHERE    datestamp > date_add(now(), INTERVAL -30 day) 
AND      season = "2016-2017" 
AND      (( 
                           playerid = "AnthonyFlorentinoProvidence" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:55:56' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-08 17:34:19') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "AnthonyFlorentinoProvidence" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-15 12:49:50' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-16 11:25:34') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "AnthonyFlorentinoProvidence" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-19 14:10:31' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-22 10:30:04') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "AraNazarianNewHampshire" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:54:53' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-04 08:54:17') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "AraNazarianNewHampshire" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-22 10:30:04' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-23 12:27:46') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "BoboCarpenterBostonUniversity" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:54:21' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-04 08:54:17') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "BoboCarpenterBostonUniversity" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-08 11:55:23' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "BrandonHickeyBostonUniversity" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:55:46' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-04 08:54:18') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "BrandonHickeyBostonUniversity" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-08 17:34:19' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-23 12:27:46') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "CallumFryerUMassachusetts" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-23 12:27:46' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "ColinWhiteBostonCollege" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:53:45' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-04 12:00:31') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "ColinWhiteBostonCollege" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-07 11:11:33' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-15 12:49:50') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "ColinWhiteBostonCollege" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-16 11:25:34' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "ConnorLaCouveeBostonUniversity" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:56:40' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "CoreyRonanConnecticut" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:57:37' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-12 09:57:32') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "CoreyRonanConnecticut" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-15 12:49:50' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-22 10:30:04') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "CoreyRonanConnecticut" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-23 12:27:46' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "DylanMalmquistNotreDame" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-04 08:54:18' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-16 11:25:34') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "DylanMalmquistNotreDame" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-19 14:10:30' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "JakeKamrassMassachusettsLowell" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:55:08' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-08 11:55:23') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "JakeKamrassMassachusettsLowell" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-12 09:57:32' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-16 11:25:34') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "JakeOettingerBostonUniversity" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:56:27' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "JasonSalvaggioNewHampshire" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-04 12:00:00' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-07 11:11:33') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "JDDudekBostonCollege" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-04 12:02:59' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-08 11:55:23') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "JDDudekBostonCollege" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-16 11:25:34' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-19 14:10:30') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "JDDudekBostonCollege" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-23 12:27:46' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "JohnEdwardhMassachusettsLowell" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-04 08:54:17' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-23 12:27:46') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "JordanGrossNotreDame" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-04 08:54:18' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "KevinIrwinVermont" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-04 08:54:17' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-04 11:59:11') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "MatiasClelandNewHampshire" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:55:29' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-04 08:54:18') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "MatiasClelandNewHampshire" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-08 11:55:23' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-19 14:10:30') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "MatiasClelandNewHampshire" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-22 10:30:04' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-23 12:27:46') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "MichaelKimBostonCollege" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-04 08:54:18' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-08 11:55:23') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "MichaelKimBostonCollege" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-16 11:25:34' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-19 14:10:30') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "MichaelKimBostonCollege" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-22 10:30:04' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "PatrickHarperBostonUniversity" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:54:40' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-04 08:54:17') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "PatrickHarperBostonUniversity" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-08 11:55:23' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "WilliamLagessonUMassachusetts" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:56:12' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-15 12:49:50') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "WilliamLagessonUMassachusetts" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-19 14:10:31' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-22 10:30:04') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "WilliamLagessonUMassachusetts" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-23 12:27:46' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59')) 
GROUP BY playerid 
ORDER BY sum(totalpoints) DESC
```

The issue is that the sum of points for `JakeOettingerBostonUniversity` **should be 22. This query returns 21.** Note that `JakeOettingerBostonUniversity` only occurs once where others may occur multiple times.

[Source Data From fch_consolidated_results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg59D.png)

What confused me further was when I started removing portions of the query as a debugging strategy. I found that if I remove the bottom 5 `OR` clauses, it returns the proper number.

```
SELECT   sum(totalpoints), 
         playerid 
FROM     fch_consolidated_results 
WHERE    datestamp > date_add(now(), INTERVAL -30 day) 
AND      season = "2016-2017" 
AND      (( 
                           playerid = "AnthonyFlorentinoProvidence" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:55:56' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-08 17:34:19') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "AnthonyFlorentinoProvidence" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-15 12:49:50' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-16 11:25:34') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "AnthonyFlorentinoProvidence" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-19 14:10:31' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-22 10:30:04') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "AraNazarianNewHampshire" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:54:53' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-04 08:54:17') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "AraNazarianNewHampshire" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-22 10:30:04' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-23 12:27:46') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "BoboCarpenterBostonUniversity" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:54:21' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-04 08:54:17') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "BoboCarpenterBostonUniversity" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-08 11:55:23' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "BrandonHickeyBostonUniversity" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:55:46' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-04 08:54:18') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "BrandonHickeyBostonUniversity" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-08 17:34:19' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-23 12:27:46') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "CallumFryerUMassachusetts" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-23 12:27:46' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "ColinWhiteBostonCollege" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:53:45' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-04 12:00:31') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "ColinWhiteBostonCollege" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-07 11:11:33' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-15 12:49:50') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "ColinWhiteBostonCollege" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-16 11:25:34' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "ConnorLaCouveeBostonUniversity" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:56:40' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "CoreyRonanConnecticut" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:57:37' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-12 09:57:32') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "CoreyRonanConnecticut" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-15 12:49:50' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-22 10:30:04') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "CoreyRonanConnecticut" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-23 12:27:46' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "DylanMalmquistNotreDame" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-04 08:54:18' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-16 11:25:34') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "DylanMalmquistNotreDame" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-19 14:10:30' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "JakeKamrassMassachusettsLowell" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:55:08' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-08 11:55:23') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "JakeKamrassMassachusettsLowell" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-12 09:57:32' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-16 11:25:34') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "JakeOettingerBostonUniversity" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:56:27' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "JasonSalvaggioNewHampshire" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-04 12:00:00' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-07 11:11:33') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "JDDudekBostonCollege" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-04 12:02:59' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-08 11:55:23') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "JDDudekBostonCollege" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-16 11:25:34' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-19 14:10:30') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "JDDudekBostonCollege" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-23 12:27:46' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "JohnEdwardhMassachusettsLowell" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-04 08:54:17' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-23 12:27:46') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "JordanGrossNotreDame" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-04 08:54:18' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "KevinIrwinVermont" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-04 08:54:17' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-04 11:59:11') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "MatiasClelandNewHampshire" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:55:29' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-04 08:54:18') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "MatiasClelandNewHampshire" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-08 11:55:23' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-19 14:10:30') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "MatiasClelandNewHampshire" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-22 10:30:04' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-23 12:27:46') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "MichaelKimBostonCollege" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-04 08:54:18' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-08 11:55:23') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "MichaelKimBostonCollege" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-16 11:25:34' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-19 14:10:30') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "MichaelKimBostonCollege" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-22 10:30:04' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
        /* BEGIN REMOVED CLAUSES
          OR       ( 
                           playerid = "PatrickHarperBostonUniversity" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:54:40' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-04 08:54:17') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "PatrickHarperBostonUniversity" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-08 11:55:23' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "WilliamLagessonUMassachusetts" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-01 15:56:12' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-15 12:49:50') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "WilliamLagessonUMassachusetts" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-19 14:10:31' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2016-10-22 10:30:04') 
         OR       ( 
                           playerid = "WilliamLagessonUMassachusetts" 
                  AND      datestamp > '2016-10-23 12:27:46' 
                  AND      datestamp < '2099-12-31 23:59:59')
                  */
                  ) 
GROUP BY playerid 
ORDER BY sum(totalpoints) DESC
```

Removing some of the clauses gives different numbers.

- `JakeOettingerBostonUniversity` still has his one clause, but I am getting a different sum.
- `JohnEdwardhMassachusettsLowell` was not removed as part of commenting out, but he is getting a different sun as well.

[Actual Results From Each Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMvjz.png)

I'm wondering if my issue something odd I am doing with the GROUP BY that is causing this, and why the presence (or not) of unrelated records is affecting my sums.

These examples were run on 2016-10-24 ensuring that the 30-day filter at the top is not a factor.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: [CHECK TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/check-table.html)?

Comment: Thank you, I ran a CHECK and an ANALYZE, both came back OK, as well as a FLUSH. I am still getting the same result.

Comment: Found the solution: The problem was that the the table from which the SQL was generated had the playerID value collated as latin1_swedish_ci. The fch_consolidated_results table has playerID collated as utf8_general_ci. In the course of the data moving around, I believe the source table ended up with values with inconsistent character sets.